# ImageView not showing shadow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, shadow

I am tring to put shadow on an `UIImageview` in the below manner:

```
imageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
imageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

But when the `UIImageview` no image or background color as clear color shadow does not show.
I have even tried to put transparent image, but it still it did not show. Please help.

Comment: Why would you expect there to be a shadow if your `UIImageView` is completely transparent? A shadow of what??

Comment: Maybe your imageView itself is in a superview that has the same size and that has clipsToBounds=YES ?

Comment: So you want there to be a shadow when there is nothing to have a shadow of?

Answer (score 5):

If the image view doesn't contain anything, there is nothing to make a shadow of. What you can do in this case is define an explicit shadow rect, rather than using the image contents:

```
CGPathRef shadowPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(imageView.bounds, NULL);
imageView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
CGPathRelease(shadowPath);
```

In fact when it comes to adding shadows in general, this technique can offer significant performance gains because the shadow doesn't need to be calculated dynamically from the layer contents. You can use this technique to improve scrolling performance, as an example. Apple mentions this in one of their WWDC videos.

Comment: +1 as I like this to the point I might change some code myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a shadow with out an image then go for `Mike Weller's` solution of the `explicit shadow rect`, I will be honest I like that answer better then mine but as an alternative you could try setting `maskToBOunds` to `NO` and adding a `shadowPath` like:

```
 // Set your basic shadow properties.
 imageView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor purpleColor] CGColor];
 imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
 imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.0f);
 imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;

 // Unmask from bounds
 imageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

 // Create a UIBezierPath
 UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageView.bounds];

 // Set the UIBezierPath (path) to the shadowPath
 imageView.layer.shadowPath = [path CGPath];
```

Be pre-warned this can affect performance if used on a lot of things, but if used on one or two things I have only ever notices a smaller if any performance hit.

But like I say I like `Mike Weller's` solution I like it so much I might change so code myself. I am only offering an alternative.